# help on how to include term $\exp(β_t)/(1+\exp(β_t))$ in AR(2) model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to include a term in an AR(2) model:
$$Y_t=\left( a_0+a_1 \frac{\exp(\beta_t)}{1+\exp(\beta_t)}\right)Y_{t-1}+bY_{t-2}+\delta\epsilon_t$$

Can anyone please help me with this? I don't seem to be able include this in the R code.

```
data=read.table("water.txt",header=T)
n=ncol(data)
koef=matrix(0,n-1,4) 
rownames(koef)=names(data)[-1] 
colnames(koef)=c("a1","a2","var.a1","var.a2")
for(i in 2:n) {
      ser=log(data[,i])
      ar2=arima(ser,order=c(2,0,0),xreg=data$year)
          koef[i-1,1]=ar2$coef[1]
      koef[i-1,2]=ar2$coef[2]
          koef[i-1,3]=ar2$var.coef[1,1]
      koef[i-1,4]=ar2$var.coef[2,2]
}

data:
yr  water
1986    0.01
1987    -0.63
1988    -0.14
1989    2.52
1990    1.96
1991    0.6
1992    1.82
1993    1.82
1994    0.89
1995    1.32
1996    -1.43
1997    0.75
1998    0.02
1999    0.69
2000    1.65
2001    -1
2002    0.66
2003    0.09
2004    -0.08
2005    0.4
2006    -0.87
2007    1.2
2008    1.1
2009    0.07
2010    -2.57
```

Comment: Please clarify your equation. Either use the appropriate (tex-based) mark-up or add parentheses.

Comment: This is not an AR(2) model. you can't estimate it with arima

Answer (score 1):

If you treat $\beta_t$ as a time-varying coefficient, then it looks like you will have to estimate more unknowns than available data.

If on the other hand $\beta_t$ is treated as a random variable following the standard logistic distribution, and if the process $\{\beta_t\}$ is i.i.d and independent of $Y_{t-1}$, then the random variable

$$U_t = \frac{\exp(\beta_t)}{1+\exp(\beta_t)} \sim U[0,1]$$

i.e. it follows a uniform in $[0,1]$, since its functional form is the cumulative distribution function of a standard logistic random variable (this is the "probability integral transform" result).
Then you have ($\mathcal F_{t-1}$ is data available up to $t-1$)

$$E[Y_t\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]=a_0Y_{t-1} + a_1E[U_tY_{t-1}\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]+bY_{t-2}+\delta E[\epsilon_t \mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]$$

$$\Rightarrow E[Y_t\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]=a_0Y_{t-1} + a_1E[U_t\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]Y_{t-1}+bY_{t-2}$$

$$\Rightarrow E[Y_t\mid \mathcal F_{t-1}]=\left(a_0 + \frac 12 a_1\right)Y_{t-1}+bY_{t-2}$$

Of course I cannot know if this formulation is useful to you, since it does not provide an estimate for the series $\{\beta_t\}$ which could be your desired target.
This formulation assumes that 
$$\beta_t \sim \Lambda \left (0, \frac {\pi^2}{3}\right)$$

You could extend this to a stable autocorrelated series for $\beta_t$.

Comment: What will the end result of estimation procedure will be? An equation with a time varying coefficient on $Y_{t-1}$? If yes, this time-varying coefficient will have to be expressed as a _function_ of something so that it can change as time passes - a function of the index $t$ or of its own past. How the estimation algorithm will produce one or the other?